# Why do my indexes in SQL Server not work on a different server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table with a lot of records. When I use database on a different server, my indexes are not being used by SQL Server! But on my own server, they are used.

The two servers have the same statistics.

Comment: Are the servers the same SQL Server version?  Do the databases have the same data?

Comment: sql server 2012 and have same data .

Comment: @richard you have indexes but not working right ? if this is the case please try with one by checking status and re-building it.

Comment: Hi Bohara.
My indexes work in my server but not working on another server !
Two Server have same data and same statistics.

Comment: Compare the execution plan for the query for both servers. Find index usage for both servers.  Are the same queries run on both servers.?

Comment: Can you supply the query you are using, the table definition, the index definitions and the execution plans. With this I can assist you.